# Rewrite rules issue with two variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to introduce two URL path rewrites but for some reason it does not work as expected.

I am trying to rewrite:
**/styles/democlient/main.css** to **_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css** in the first instance. The second 'styles' rule works as expected, only the first one doesn't.

I added `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` to my Apache vhosts configuration to make it easier to track. It seems to me that when mod is reaching the first 'style' rule then it does not stop and for some reason tries to match it to the second one.

My .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule styles/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*) _projects/$1/public/styles/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule styles/(.*) public/styles/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My logtrack

```
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] add path info postfix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/styles -> E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/styles/democlient/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/styles/democlient/main.css -> styles/democlient/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] applying pattern 'styles/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*)' to uri 'styles/democlient/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] rewrite 'styles/democlient/main.css' -> '_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] add per-dir prefix: _projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css -> E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip document_root prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css -> /_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] internal redirect with /_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css -> _projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] applying pattern 'styles/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*)' to uri '_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css -> _projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] applying pattern 'styles/(.*)' to uri '_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] rewrite '_projects/democlient/public/styles/main.css' -> 'public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] add per-dir prefix: public/styles/main.css -> E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip document_root prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css -> /public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] internal redirect with /public/styles/main.css [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css -> public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] applying pattern 'styles/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*)' to uri 'public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] strip per-dir prefix: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css -> public/styles/main.css[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] applying pattern 'styles/(.*)' to uri 'public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] rewrite 'public/styles/main.css' -> 'public/styles/main.css'
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] add per-dir prefix: public/styles/main.css -> E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css
[perdir E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: E:/www/WEB_tech4rec/public/styles/main.css [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

If you could help me find the reason, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `^` before your styles RewriteRules and prevent your last RewriteRules to redirect physical files.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^styles/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*) _projects/$1/public/styles/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*) public/styles/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```